# Is it possible to stop the respawning guard posts system in Far Cry 2?

Tags: far-cry-2

There is a system of auto repop in Far Cry 2. Is it possible to stop it or to increase the spawn time?

Comment: whooooooooooops

Comment: Yeah, it's annoying to clear a base and then drive 100 meters and come back to find the base is repopulated...

Answer (score 5):

No. Fortunately, Ubisoft admitted that FC2's respawn rate is absurd and FC3 should have it fixed.

Comment: Do you know that creating a mod isn't possible? Have you researched this topic?

Comment: Have I mentioned anything about a mod, @user598527?

Answer (score 5):

You don't say what platform you're on, but on PC you can install [Dylan's Far Cry 2 Realism Mod](http://www.moddb.com/mods/dylans-far-cry-2-realism-mod)

While this doesn't stop the respawning, it makes the bad guys significantly less likely to notice you when driving through.

> Checkpoint guards now have a 60% chance to chase you after passing
>   through, as opposed to 90%-100% in vanilla.