# Far Cry 3 - How Increase Enemies And Enviromental Hostility In FC3

Tags: far-cry-3

I have already read the following [post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/106647/capturing-all-outposts-in-far-cry-3).

Once the player has beaten Far Cry 3, they have the option of resetting all of the enemy outposts. The new outposts either seem easier to take down, or my single player abilities have increased even on Master difficulty. In either case, Far Cry 2 seemed more fun later on in the game when there were random skirmishes available at any guardpost (although this was annoying to many and something they meant to correct in FC3).

I am wondering the follwing:

1. Is it possible to increase/assign how many and what type of enemies are at an outpost?
2. Increase the number and type of roving patrols through hostile areas?
3. Keep areas hostile even after an outpost has been taken down (to keep roving patrols).
4. Otherwise increase the difficulty and interactivity of single player gameplay after besting the main storyline of the game.
5. If possible, I would prefer not using mods (very unlikely, as I would have found these options somewhere) so can I make any of these mods myself by editing a config file? If not, please mention any other mods that may do what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done through modding. An existing mod that does what you want is [**Gyga Island**](http://www.nexusmods.com/farcry3/mods/147/?).

Features are:

- Infested Island: after you unlock an outpost, enemy encounters will remain (optional)
- No alarms: if the enemy spots you, reinforcements will appear, without them needing to raise the alarm (optional)
- Balanced and incremented the amount of enemies and vehicles in both islands (including in outposts)
- Heavy pirates added in path patrols
- Regular or frenetic (enemies will spawn near you) encounter spawn
- Choice between amount of encounters and outpost density (low to very high)

Comment: Oh thank you @GreatModGod. Before I green check this, and for completeness, can you also choose the type of enemies that will show up at outposts, etc. so that there will be variety?

Comment: Also, is this a new island, or the same two islands used in the regular single player storyline?

Comment: @user58446 You can't specify the types of enemies in outposts, only how many there will be (density). It's the same islands as the vanilla game.

Comment: ...and I'm guessing you've used this mod and your rig didn't turn into a bot, right?  Thanks again, answer awarded.

Comment: @user58446 Yes, I've used it myself, but merged with another mod ([New Game Plus and Privateer Outfit Mod Fixed](http://www.nexusmods.com/farcry3/mods/131/?)). Back up your save file before using a new mod, in case there are issues. You can view and modify the mod itself using [Gibbed Dunia 2 Tools](http://svn.gib.me/builds/dunia2/). There are instructions on unpacking/extracting the files from Gyga Island's description page.

Answer (score 0):

None of those options exist in the single player except for changing the overall difficulty of the game, which can be found in the menu screen. The patrols reset when you reset the outposts. If your looking for more of a challenge, you can try the forts, otherwise there is no way to interactively change the outposts.

Comment: Are any mode available? Is this even possible through modding?